# regex to pull part of the string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file read as an array. I am checking each line of this array and trying to extract a part of the line in a Perl script if it matches the pattern.

```
  ---                                                                     
   Message '/com/java/deploy/mess1' on folder1 'f1' is running.                             

   Additional thread instances: '0'                                        
   Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Jar file '/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess1ENV11122013.jar'
   Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.                                         
   Long description: ''                                                    

   ---                                                                     
   Message '/com/java/deploy/mess2' on folder1 'f1' is running.                             

   Additional thread instances: '0'                                        
   Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Jar file '/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess2ENV11122013.jar'
   Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.                                         
   Long description: ''                                                    
   ----                                                                    
   Message '/com/java/deploy/mess3' on folder1 'f1' is running.                             

   Additional thread instances: '0'                                        
   Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Jar file '/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess3ENV11122013.jar'
   Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.                                         
   Long description: ''
```

I am searching for the mess1 and trying to extract the jar info from the above array.

```
foreach $line (@messdetials) {

  if ($line =~ mess1) {
    next if /^(\s)*$/;

    if (/in Jar file '(.*?)'/) {
      @jardetails = `$displaycommand -b $1`;
      print @jardetails;
    }
```

I am hoping to extract `/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess1.jar` fron the array and run a inhouse script against it, but I don't see any output.

Comment: So each line above is a single element in your array or each block is a single element? (blocks being separated by --)

Comment: Should `if ($line=~mess1){` be `if ($line=~/mess1/){`? Notice I added the forward slashes.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: That amounts to the same thing. It isn't complaining because the OP clearly doesn't have `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: @user3154754: I have tidied your code so that it is more readable. It has two levels of mismatched braces so it doesn't compile. Have you not tried any further than this? If not then it's very lazy to ask a question here to get it fixed. You also *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Comment: @Hunter, i have been looking at this wrong. I think i have been treating each line a single element in my array. But my script should check if the line has mess1 or mess2 or mess3 and then get the jar for that corresponding mess.

Comment: @Borodin,@bloodyKuncles, i am running this as a part of a larger script. What i have pasted here is just a snippet of my script. I am using strict and wanrnings.

Comment: @user3164754: If you really have `use strict` in place, then you shouldn't be posting code that you know very well doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

This will do as you ask. It expects the path to the inpu file as a parameter on the command line, like this

```
perl findjar.pl /path/to/mylog.log
```

**findjar.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mess;
while (<>) {
  if ( /^\s*Message\s*'([^']*)'/ ) {
    $mess = $1;
  }
  elsif ( /in Jar file '([^']*)'/ ) {
    print $1, "\n" if $mess and $mess eq 'mess1';
  }
}
```

**output**

```
/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess1.jar
```

Comment: `((?:/\w+)*?/mess1\.jar)` seems like a simpler search since the jar files appear to be named after the search term.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: I assumed that wasn't the case in reality, otherwise there's little point in the program at all. It could be reduced to `print "/deploy/ENV/folder1/mess1.jar\n"`

Comment: Fair enough, thought it was worth mentioning. Hard to tell with no feedback after the question was posted.

Comment: I modified the original post a little bit. The jar files are not exactly named after the search term.

Comment: I have tried with this following `foreach $line (@messdetials){    
        next if ($line=~/$mess1/);             
        if ( $line =~ /in Bar file '([^']*)'/){   
        print "$1\n";                             
        @jardetails = `$displaycommand -b $1`;
       print @jardetails;
        }` but this cant hold it to just the first block. It's going ahead with mess2 and mess3 jars too.

Comment: @user3164754: That's nothing like the solution I've posted.

Comment: @Borodin, I took the regex from your solution. For some reason, the regex was what i was struggling with. Need to do some more studying about regex. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve this by using the following code snippet.

```
 if ($line=~/$flowname/){$flag=1;}
 if($flag==1){
 if ($line =~/in Jar file '([^']*)'/){
 @jardetails = `$displaycommand -b $1`;
 print @jardetails;
 }
 $flag=0;}
```

This is working for me.